# How to write redirection rules for missing pages

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a html page like http://test.com/en/about.html but if someone tries http://test.com/zh/about.html which is not available on server.

Is there any way to redirect it to http://test.com/en/about.html using .htaccess file. If yes how can write such rules.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace a page with another, it is just a simple [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^zh/about.html$ /en/about.html [R,L]
```

---

If you want to redirect all pages to the English counterpart, you must first capture the part after the language, and append it to `en`. But you must be careful and check, if it is already `en`. Otherwise, you would have a rewrite loop

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteRule ^../(.*)$ /en/$1 [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)). *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

---

To have any other length prefix, use `.+?` instead of `..`. This looks for one or more instead of just two characters

```
RewriteRule ^.+?/(.*)$ /en/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: zh id not fixed.. its can be anything like abc/about.html etc.

Comment: Thanks Olap, For your help, I made some changes in it and it worked well